# One model, multiple view models and an updatable view using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a BPMN editor using WPF and need to include, among other things, a set of different *task* types.
Each task type share some common properties, but also include some type-specific information.
However, for a given task element, the user should be able to change its type and even the information specific to the given task type should be retained between such changes.

Therefore, I thought about creating:

- one model class, `TaskModel`, which would combine properties of all task types
- a separate `XXXTaskViewModel` class for each task type, exposing only properties related to that type
- a common `TaskView` class representing the task as a visual element in the editor canvas

When a user changes the type of a task (using a property grid), a `PropertyChanged` event is fired, which is handled in `TaskView` to change the `DataContext` view model for the new one.

Since I'm totally new to C# and need to refactor and enhance someone else's code, my initial questions are:

- Is such a design correct, i.e., in accordance with MVVM principles? Or maybe there exist other better patterns/solutions I could use?
- Is it possible at all to handle `PropertyChanged` events in a view?

---

I tried to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my view (to change `DataContext`):

```cs
public partial class BaseElementView : DragableUserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BaseElementView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
    }

    private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A property has changed: " + e.PropertyName);  // just a proof-of-concept
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, no `PropertyChanged` is actually catched (although the same event is handled by a view model class). Also, I get a code analyzer hint:

> The event `BaseElementView.PropertyChanged` is never used.

I don't know why that happend.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` has to be implemented by the ViewModel (and other similar objects) - the View itself uses [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.8) (for bindable properties) or simple events for change notification.

Comment: When you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then **you** (your class) have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event - see [example](https://gist.github.com/mariodivece/9907870#file-viewmodelbase-cs-L45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I found a solution to my problem - I've created a *model* containing all properties (for all different kind of tasks), a *view model* bound to that model (i.e., also containing all properties) and then dynamically adjusted the `Browsable` attribute of the appropriate properties in the *view model* (in the setter of the `TaskType` property).

This post was helpful to adjust the `Browsable` attribute: [Make a Property Read-Only in PropertyGrid](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/make-a-property-read-only-in-propertygrid/)

I adjusted the proposed method to handle the `BrowsableAttribute` attribute:

```cs
public static void SetBrowsableAttribute(this PropertyDescriptor p, bool value)
{
    var attributes = p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Where(x => !(x is BrowsableAttribute)).ToList();
    attributes.Add(new BrowsableAttribute(value));
    typeof(MemberDescriptor).GetProperty("AttributeArray", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(p, attributes.ToArray());
}
```

and then used it like this:

```cs
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
public TaskType Type
{
    get { return _taskActivity.Type; }
    set
    {
        _taskActivity.Type = value;

        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[nameof(AvailableImplementations)].SetBrowsableAttribute(UseImplementation);
        // ...

        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Type));
    }
}
```